# what does '<Hero[]>' mean

Tags: angular, typescript

hi I'm new to `angular` and `typescript`, and I'm trying to learn the tutorial from [angular](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6). and I found something that I don't understand what it meant. like:

1.

```
getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    console.log(this.http);
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl);
}
```

on the above example, i want to know what does `<Hero[]>` means on `Observable<Hero[]>` and `this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)`

2.

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}`);
    return of(HEROES.find(hero => hero.id === id));
}
```

check it carefully on `HeroService: fetched hero id=${id}` it wrapped with backticks (`) not single quote ('). why use it?
and last one the `HEROES.find(hero => hero.id === id)` what does `=>` means?

I'm really new to this. so, I'm so sorry if my questions offend or trigger you guys..

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [basic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) Hero[] seems to be an array of Hero.

Answer (score 2):

Method getHeroes() returns an Observable of type array's of Hero. 
And Backtick (`) is called template literal. Earlier we used to write

```
let a = 10
b = 5 ;
console.log("value of a is" + a + " and the value of b is " + b);
```

With template literals we can write

```
console.log(`value of a is ${a} and value of b is ${b}`)
```

Where ${expression} can be used to bind expression .

=> is called fat arrow .

```
let example = function(str){
  console.log(str)
}
```

Can now be written using fat arrow in this way

```
let example = (str) =>{
  console.log(str)
}
```

Please Go through the docs of ES6 for better understanding . Template literals and fat arrow are implemented in ES6 .

Answer (score 1):

**`Observable<Hero[]>`** Denotes that getHeroes method rObservable returns an Observable which wraps the data of type Hero **`Hero`** , where **`[]`** denotes an array;

**`** (backtick) is known as [**template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in javascript

An expression inside the literal (the value of which is evaluated during runtime and included in the final value produced by the literal) is enclosed in curly braces {} with a preceding dollar sign $.

Comment: You may want to rephrase this a bit to make it actually correct. E.g. what is an observable of type hero?

Comment: It would be more accurate to say `Observable<Hero>` returns an `Observable` which wraps the data of type `Hero`

Comment: @AyushGupta hmm ! added

Comment: @Sajeetharan so about `Observable<Hero[]>`.. is it like `(string)`, `(bolean)`, `(int)` in PHP?

Comment: @DennyRustandi nope you could read http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html